# ResultSet multiple rows

Tags: jdbc, resultset

I am using jdbc connection to a database and getting multiple rows as part of the ResultSet. I run a sql off of the ResultSet and somehow end up only going through the first row. For eg: query1 is my result set that generates two pid rows. I then use query2 to terminate the pid. I would like query2 to go through all the rows in query1 and execute the terminate command one after the other. Another point to note is that query1 can have more than 2 rows depending on the resultset. Below is code I am using and any help is appreciated. BTW I did try using a nested for loop in while and that does not reissue query2 as I see in the database logs.

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

                                                    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(
                                                            "SELECT \n" +
                                                                    "kl.pid as blocking_pid,\n" +
                                                                    "ka.usename as blocking_user,\n" +
                                                                    "ka.query as blocking_query,\n" +
                                                                    "bl.pid as blocked_pid,\n" +
                                                                    "a.usename as blocked_user, \n" +
                                                                    "a.query as blocked_query, \n" +
                                                                    "to_char(age(now(), a.query_start),'HH24h:MIm:SSs') as age\n" +
                                                                    "FROM pg_catalog.pg_locks bl\n" +
                                                                    "JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity a \n" +
                                                                    "ON bl.pid = a.pid\n" +
                                                                    "JOIN pg_catalog.pg_locks kl \n" +
                                                                    "ON bl.locktype = kl.locktype\n" +
                                                                    "and bl.database is not distinct from kl.database\n" +
                                                                    "and bl.relation is not distinct from kl.relation\n" +
                                                                    "and bl.page is not distinct from kl.page\n" +
                                                                    "and bl.tuple is not distinct from kl.tuple\n" +
                                                                    "and bl.virtualxid is not distinct from kl.virtualxid\n" +
                                                                    "and bl.transactionid is not distinct from kl.transactionid\n" +
                                                                    "and bl.classid is not distinct from kl.classid\n" +
                                                                    "and bl.objid is not distinct from kl.objid\n" +
                                                                    "and bl.objsubid is not distinct from kl.objsubid\n" +
                                                                    "and bl.pid <> kl.pid \n" +
                                                                    "JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity ka \n" +
                                                                    "ON kl.pid = ka.pid\n" +
                                                                    "WHERE kl.granted and not bl.granted\n" +
                                                                    "ORDER BY a.query_start");

                                                    //Get all the blocking pids and run pg_terminate_backend
                                                    while (res.next()) {
                                                         String pid = res.getString("blocking_pid");


                                                            stmt.execute("SELECT pg_terminate_backend(" + String.valueOf(pid) + ")");

                                                        }


                                                    stmt.close();
                                                    connection.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. just in case anyone is facing the same/ similar issue. I was reusing the jdbc connection in query2 with the same variable. Once I used a separate jdbc call in query2 it worked.